# VirtualBox: how do I install a specific version of Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualization, virtualbox

I'm really new to VirtualBox (and server stuff generally).

I'm using VirtualBox on MacOS and I need to install version 10.0.4 of Ubuntu.

The setup for VirtualBox only allows you to specify Linux > Ubuntu (64-bit).

How can I install a particular version?

I've been told that you can download it as a disk image and install it in VirtualBox somehow: can anyone point me at more details?

thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote? Not that I mind, would just like to know why this is an unhelpful question so I can ask a better one next time :)

Comment: @Richard - I don't know if it deserves the downvote or not, but your question is pretty far off base, due to a lack of understanding of virtualbox, and may be misleading to others. Virtualbox doesn't install a particular OS for you, it creates a virtual machine (with the OS *label* of your choosing) on which you can install a Linux distribution. Some time spent learning about Virtualbox would likely have cleared this up.

Comment: **10.04** not 10.0.4. Virtual box is just giving you an option for what type of environment you would like it to create -- i.e., an environment for an AMD64 / x86_64 bit version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox will let you install either 32- or 64-bit version of Ubuntu. Make sure you download the correct version from the Ubuntu site.

When you create your virtual machine, you'll configure it just like building a real pc. When you do this, you'll add at least one virtual hard disk, and one virtual cd/dvd drive. To install Ubuntu, add the Ubuntu iso to the cd drive, and set the system boot order to boot from the cd drive first. When you start the vm, it will boot from the iso, and you can follow the installation prompts.

After you install, it will force a restart. When the VM is just starting (it will show the VBox logo), close the window to shut down the machine. Then edit the VM settings and remove the iso from the cd drive, otherwise it will reboot the live cd.

Once you're booted to the hard drive, you'll want to run updates, reboot, and then install the VBox guest additions from the vm menu bar.

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify: after I've downloaded the iso, I actually need to burn a CD, and put it in the CD drive? Then when I set up the VM, I will see an option to boot from a CD? (which I'm not seeing at the moment)

Comment: No. Once you have set up the Virtualbox system for Ubuntu, you can start the system up (without Ubuntu installed yet, just an empty environment). It will prompt you for an ISO. You can browse your filesystem for the ISO. There is no booting or burning.

Comment: @Richard - You don't _need_ to burn a cd, but can if you want one around. There is a drop down menu for the virtual cd that lets you point it to an actual drive (actual cd in the drive), or point it towards an image file(your iso). So it works the same way, but loading from the iso will be faster since the file is on your hard drive, not on an actual cd.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this site: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download and select version 10.04 in the download options. Then select if you need 32bit or 64bit and then click download.